# Python module code says path doesn't exist but is readable and statable

Tags: python, windows

I'm running into a really bizarre problem in a python module and I'm not sure whether or not it's due to some python weirdness or some brokenness in windows or the filesystem being in a weird state.

Here's the problem: a module I'm using creates some output that goes into a specified directory, and it creates that directory if it doesn't exist. This works fine if you run it once, running it a second time the module thinks that the directory doesn't exist, tries to create it, then bombs out with a "Cannot create a file when that file already exists" error.

So, I went digging. In my main script I can run os.path.exists on the directory and it says it exists just fine. In the module the same exact code returns false however. Also in the module if I do an os.access(*path*, os.R_OK) it returns true, indicating the path is readable, and if I do an os.stat(*path*) it returns file info, indicating the path exists.

If I run the same code manually in a python shell it all works fine, says the path exists, etc.

Here's some code and the outputs:

In my main script:

```
print('Path {} exists: {} - readable: {} - stat: {}', 
    filename, 
    os.path.exists(filename), 
    os.access(filename, os.R_OK), 
    os.stat(filename))
```

Output:

```
File testoutput exists: True - readable: True - stat: nt.stat_result(st_mode=16895, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0L, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=0L, st_atime=1508458382L, st_mtime=1508458382L, st_ctime=1508458382L)
```

Inside the module, the same code:

```
File testoutput exists: False - readable: True - stat: nt.stat_result(st_mode=16895, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0L, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=0L, st_atime=1508458382L, st_mtime=1508458382L, st_ctime=1508458382L)
```

What the heck is going on here? Is the module code running in some sort of different context with different permissions? Is my filesystem broken in some weird way?

Also, I should mention that all of this is being done in an elevated cmd shell so that's not the problem.

---

**Solved:**

It turned out to be some intervening code that was monkey patching os.path.exists, the most helpful tool was using reflection and the "inspect" module to figure out where the code was actually coming from, specifically:

```
    print('os.path: {} - {} - {} - {}'.format(os.__file__, os.path.__name__, os.path.__file__, os.path.exists.__module__))
    print(inspect.getsource(os.path.exists))
```

The __module__ info told me where the monkeypatching was happening.

Comment: Could you show the code?

Comment: All paths are absolute, i.e. starting with drive letter or server name?

Comment: @MichaelButscher the behavior is the same with absolute or relative paths.

Comment: `os.path.exists` calls `os.stat` and returns false only if `OSError` is raised. Please change your test to call `os.stat` directly.

Comment: Windows `os.access` with `R_OK` just checks that the file or directory exists. It's assumed that all files and directories can be read. NT ACLs can deny read access, but Windows `os.access` and `os.chmod` were never extended beyond DOS file attributes.

Comment: @eryksun see update, os.stat works fine in both contexts.

Comment: `os.path.exists` returns false only if `os.stat` raises `OSError`, in both Python 2 and 3. Confirm that `os.__file__` and `os.path.__file__` are correct for your installation of Python. Include the source printed by `import inspect;` `print(inspect.getsource(os.path.exists))`.

Comment: @eryksun I was heading down that route myself. os.__file__ is 'c:\python27\lib\os.pyc' for both, os.path.__name__ is 'ntpath' for both, os.path.__file__ is 'c:\python27\lib\ntpath.pyc' for both. inspect.getsource shows the expected os.stat code from the script but raises a 'source code not available' IOError from the module.

Comment: Ensure that `os.path.exists.__module__` is "genericpath" in both cases. If not, apparently something is monkeypatching it or accidentally overwriting it. Review the bytecode from `dis.dis(os.path.exists)`.

Comment: Ahah! That did it. Turns out there was some other code running elsewhere that was monkeypatching os.path.exists and screwing everything up, it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an educated guess. `os.path.exists` will return `False` for a broken symlink, while `os.access` will report the file itself (the symlink) as being readable. Is it possible your file is a symlink?

Another difference is that `os.access` will use the real (not effective) uid/gid to test readability while `os.path.exists` uses the effective uid/gid. Is it possible there is a change of user ID between the modules?

Comment: Nope, it's just a regular directory.

Comment: Is there a different way to determine effective uid on windows? I tried getpass.getuser() and it was identical in both contexts.

Comment: @Wedge, `os.access` just calls `GetFileAttributes` on Windows to check that the file exists and whether the read-only attribute is set. It doesn't do anything with NT security descriptors, access control lists, or thread impersonation to support file systems that implement security such as NTFS. A proposed patch that implements this has drifted in limbo for years because there isn't any real demand for it.